# Ksh compound variable referencing

Tags: ksh, variable

I would like to use KSH feature called compound variable to show better what's going on in the code.

On the other hand my the interesting values are held in number organized array.
I would like to bound compound variable to array representative like this

```
typeset -n person.name=person_arr[0]
typeset -n person.surname=person_arr[1]
```

But as a result I got

```
ksh: typeset: person.name: is not an identifier
```

The question is whether compound variables can go with variable referencing and if not how to use int indexed arrays in more elegant way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer is to set `NAME=0 SURNAME=1` and use these variables instead of 0 and 1 indexes in your array, however ...

You can do what you want in a rather longwinded way using **discipline functions**. Each variable can have a function `set()` defined for it; it will be called every time the variable is changed. Similarly for `get()`. So you can do the following:

```
#!/bin/ksh
typeset -C person
function person.name.set {
    person_arr[0]=${.sh.value}
}
function person.name.get {
    .sh.value=${person_arr[0]}
}
function person.surname.set {
    person_arr[1]=${.sh.value}
}
function person.surname.get {
    .sh.value=${person_arr[1]}
}

typeset -a person_arr
person_arr[0]=first   person_arr[1]=second
echo "name is ${person.name} ${person.surname}"

person.name=first2    person.surname=second2
echo "name is ${person.name} ${person.surname}"
echo "name is ${person_arr[@]}"
```

This declares a compound variable `person`, and discipline functions for the subnames `.name` and `.surname`.  The `set()` functions set the appropriate `person_arr` indexed value to the new value (in `.sh.value`), and the `get()` functions "return" the appropriate indexed value by setting `.sh.value`.

The example sets the array version to one value, then overwrites them with the compound names. The output is

```
name is first second
name is first2 second2
name is first2 second2
```

If you have several variables you want to bind in this way you should look for a solution using [your own ksh type](http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2010/05/ksh93-using-types-to-create-object-orientated-scripts.html).

Comment: Thank you script is what I was looking for. Whole answer is even more awesome with suggested reading.

Answer (score 2):

In `ksh93`, compound variable names and `namerefs` don't go together, but it works the other way around:

```
typeset -n First=person.name       
typeset -n Last=person.surname
person.name=John
person.surname=Doe
echo $First $Last
John Doe
```